# Jython error 'ImportError: No module named type_check'

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, jython, inertial-navigation

I'm working on a quick interface to allow the use of the 9 DOF IMU in the rpi sense hat from java and I can't seem to get the python to work out. I have added the python 2.7 libraries into the sys path of the Jython environment but it still can't find this 'type_check' module.

Here is the java code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter;

SenseHat()
{
    interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    interpreter.exec("import sys");
    interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')");
    interpreter.exec("from sense_hat import SenseHat");
    interpreter.exec("sense = SenseHat()");
    PyObject result = interpreter.eval("sense.get_temperature()");
    System.out.println(result.toString());
    interpreter.close();
}
```

which attempts to use the RPI sense hat python API.
When executed I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .sense_hat import SenseHat, SenseHat as AstroPi
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
ImportError: No module named type_check
```

Comment: Your `numpy` installation is not valid. Check on `IDLE`(on terminal) for see what happening !

Comment: It works fine in a normal python environment this is a jython specific problem

Comment: Validate your sub module `from .type_check import *` maybe change name ! So `from type_check import *`, this is are same ? @mattcow12 
This original trace-back ? How to add a `.` after `from`?

Comment: Tried that just got this output:
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named type_check

Comment: If NumPy is required, then I think it's going to be difficult to make this work with Jython. https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython

Comment: Replace `from .type_check import *` to `from numpy.lib.type_check import *` **on** `"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py"`. What a foolish error. So can't resolve `numpy` initial path argument, `.` is `cwd` but no idea, replace all `.` to `numpy.lib`. Additional: `Check **jython** maximum path string length ` !